# Android View System

Tags: android, ios

In iOS the "Window" is only one usually. And we can change the window's RootViewController and then the RootViewController's view is shown on screen. 
How about android?
[image]

Is this picture real??? the PhoneWindow is under Activity? 
If this is true, What is "Super Top View" on android like "Window" in iOS ( iOS's "Window" encompass all controller's view if the controller is window's RootViewController Right? )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding View objects

In Android every views are inside the  [Layouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) thats in xml format even its activity or fragment its does not matter.

And also we can create custom views(button,textview...) and layout without xml data using programmatically java code.

Refer for more details 
[LayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)